# Run java application as windows service (using jsl) - get error when installing

Tags: java, windows-services

Get a problem when installing java application as service in windows environment(Win 7). use jsl
http://jslwin.sourceforge.net/ to launch application

when installing with jsl -install

> error message  : OpenScManager failed - Access is denied. <0x5>

but application run when jsl -run , i already log in as administrate but java application not install as service (not shows up in the service.msc), any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use 'run-as-administrator'.  Even if logged in as administrator  programs will not run using the elevated privileges. This enhances the security(or reduces accidental damages)

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/user-account-control

Comment: Thank you it works, to open cmd prompt as admin can use this http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/