# Will this Java service make use of the command prompt?

Tags: java, wmi, wmic

The Java code runs the command prompt and passes parameters to it, and then executes. it works fine in Eclipse IDE, but when I make it as a service (in Windows 7) and run it, it doesn't work. What I want to ask is will this service invoke the command prompt, pass parameters, and run it. Just for reference on line code is given below.

```
String status = WMI.execute(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/C", "cscript.exe", vbScriptFilePath, ipAddress, username, password, service}).split(WMI.CRLF)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is windows 7. It may have user access control enabled.(why not?).

In that case starting service is only done with process with administrative permissions. The user being administrator is not enough. See this question/answer and comments 
[Run java application as windows service (using jsl) - get error when installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732967/run-java-application-as-windows-service-using-jsl-get-error-when-installing/9733042#9733042)

Comment: the service gets installed. but it is not able to process the code line which i have mentioned in the question

Comment: @user1069186: Oh. I added wmi tags to your question. Please try to give more details about the problem.

Comment: @Jayan Why? What does wmi have to do with it?